# Duality in the Derived Category and Resolutions

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, sheaf-theory

Let $X$ be a smooth algebraic variety.  In addition, assume it to be a compact Calabi-Yau, $\omega_{X} \cong \mathcal{O}_{X}$.  I have a coherent sheaf $\mathscr{F}$ on $X$ which is torsion-free, but not locally-free and it is resolved by vector bundles $\mathscr{A}$ and $\mathscr{B}$ as

$$0 \to \mathscr{A} \to \mathscr{B} \to \mathscr{F} \to 0.$$

Now, an object in the derived category $D^{b}(\text{Coh}(X))$ in which I am particularly interested, is not the complex $[\mathscr{A} \to \mathscr{B}]$, but rather $[\mathscr{B}^{\vee} \to \mathscr{A}^{\vee}]$.  Here, the duals are well defined since these are vector bundles, so we simply take sheaf Hom into $\mathcal{O}_{X}$.

My question is, quite simply, is the complex $[\mathscr{B}^{\vee} \to \mathscr{A}^{\vee}]$ related (in the derived category) in any way to $\mathscr{F}^{\vee}$, under some suitable definition of duality for torsion-free sheaves?  Should I be looking into Verdier duality here?

Although I know very little about it, I've seen that Verdier duality of a complex in the derived category requires applying Hom into the dualizing complex $\omega_{X}$.  Assuming $X$ is smooth, reduced I'm guessing this dualizing complex is simply zero except with the canonical bundle in degree zero.  Since I am assuming my $X$ is Calabi-Yau, I am wondering if this gives anything special.  Like, in this case is the complex $[\mathscr{A} \to \mathscr{B}]$ Verdier dual to $[\mathscr{B}^{\vee} \to \mathscr{A}^{\vee}]$?

Comment: Is the sequence you give an exact triple?

Comment: Is that the same thing as an exact triangle?  If so, then I do not believe so.  It is simply a resolution of a coherent sheaf by bundles.  I may be wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by a resolution? Does that mean that $F$ is the cokernel of $A \to B$? Or do you also assume that the kernel of $A \to B$ is zero?

Comment: good point, thanks.  after looking into it, I belive $\mathscr{F}$ is the cokernel and the kernel of $\mathscr{A} \to \mathscr{B}$ is zero as you say.  I've edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complex $B^\vee \to  A^\vee$ is the derived dual of $F$. Its relation to the standard dual is $H^0(B^\vee \to A^\vee) \cong F^\vee$, $H^1(B^\vee \to A^\vee) \cong Ext^1(F,O_X)$ (here $H^i$ stand for the cohomology sheaves of a complex, and $Ext^1$ is a local $Ext$).

In plain words, the same can be phrased by saying that there is an exact sequence
$$
0 \to F^\vee \to B^\vee \to A^\vee \to Ext^1(F,O_X) \to 0.
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot!  May I ask what exactly the derived dual is?  Are you nowhere using Verdier duality with the Calabi-Yau assumption that the dualizing complex (sheaf) is trivial $\omega_{X} \cong \mathcal{O}_{X}$?

Comment: After thinking more about it, it appears that what you're calling the derived dual is the application of $R^{\bullet}\text{Hom}( \cdot, \mathcal{O}_{X})$.  I'm sure this is standard, I just don't know too much yet.  In the Calabi-Yau case where $\omega_{X} \cong \mathcal{O}_{X}$, this agrees precisely with Verdier duality, correct?  Assuming $X$ is smooth, reduced, etc.

Comment: @StephenPietromonaco: Indeed, derived dual of $F$ is just $RHom(F,O_X)$. As for Verdier duality, it has nothing to do with all that. VD is for sheaves of abelian groups, not for coherent sheaves. For coherent sheaves there is Grothendieck duality instead, which is defined in a similar way, but is usually combined with the dimension shift.

Comment: Great, thank you.  I should read up on Grothendiek duality, but for now, I'm very happy with $[B^{\vee} \to A^{\vee}] = R^{\bullet}\text{Hom}(F, \mathcal{O}_{X})$.  I appreciate all your help here!